# Looping and changing a list - remove doesn't always work

Tags: c#, list, for-loop, windows-phone-7.1

I'm trying to go through a loop 40 times and changing a list in the process.

This is the code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)
{
    location = rand.Next(rows.Count);
    rank = rand2.Next(pondRanks.Count);
    ComputerPonds[rows[location]].Rank = (PondRank)pondRanks[rank];
    rows.Remove(location);
    pondRanks.Remove(rank);
}
```

For some reason the remove doesn't happen all the time, and only sometimes. Anyone has a suggestion?
Both of the list are List , they have 40 elements, and I want to remove the element itself.
Even when debugging I can see that the list count isn't the same (they both have the same initial numbers and they both need to do remove at this loop). If it matters, I'm working on windows phone platform..

Comment: What type is `rows` and `pondRanks`? Perhaps you meant to use `RemoveAt` instead.

Comment: As @ChrisSinclair says. RemoveAt removes at a location. Remove looks for the object

Comment: In addition to other answers, it's worth noting that your loop will only execute 39 times... you need to change it to `for (int i = 0; i <= 39; i++)` or a more preferred way `for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++)` ... maybe even extract out the hard value of 40 into a variable named iterations?

Comment: The list are int. Also, the for loop will change after I fix this bug. I want the row, location members to be removed from the list.. Thanks for all your help !

Comment: I really had to use RemoveAt .. Don't know why it took me so much time to realize ! Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 6):

I'm pretty sure you should be using [List.RemoveAt](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z.aspx) not [List.Remove](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/cd666k3e.aspx). `RemoveAt` will remove the item at the specified index, whereas `Remove` will look for *that* object you passed in and remove it from the List if it's in there. But I'm pretty sure that looking at your code that `location` and `rank` represent the *index*, not the objects themselves.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 39; i++)
{
    location = rand.Next(rows.Count);
    rank = rand2.Next(pondRanks.Count);
    ComputerPonds[location].Rank = (PondRank)pondRanks[rank];
    rows.RemoveAt(location);
    pondRanks.RemoveAt(rank);
}
```

EDIT: You may also want to consider making sure that your `rows` and `pondRanks` have enough elements (39) before starting the loop (or altering the `i < 39` to max out at the upper limit of their length)

Comment: It's also worth noting his loop will execute at maximum 39 times. The best thing to do would be to capture the iterations using something like `var iterations = Math.Min(MaxIterations, Math.Min(rows.Count, pondRanks.Count));`

Comment: Yeah, that's what I meant with my last edit, just didn't put it as well as you. :)

Comment: Even if he didn't take the list/collections count into account, his loop executes 39 times when he wanted 40. He should change 39 to 40 at the minimum.

Comment: @m-y Ahh, good pick up. I completely _glazed_ over that fact.

Comment: I want the actual member to be removed, Sorry the names are misleading.. the lists have 39 elements in it

Comment: I changed my code, I really wanted to pass the member of the list in this location. Thanks!